# Find files in some directories with particular name pattern and tar them?

Tags: linux, bash

There are many subdirectories in a directory. For example,

```
/tmp/dir/00/
/tmp/dir/01/
....
/tmp/dir/99/
```

How to `tar` all the subdirectories which name is less than `50`?

```
find /tmp/dir/ -name "???" -exec tar -rzf file1.tgz {} \;
tar -czf file1.tgz ???
```

Comment: Are there any missing numbers? If not, `tar -czf file1.tgz /tmp/dir/{00..50}/` should work fine.

Comment: Do you want to tar each matched directory individually or just one tar file for all the directories?

Comment: @anubhava, one tar for all the selected files.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the directories are just one level down from `dir/` you can do this in `bash`:

```sh
cd dir/
for d in [0-9][0-9]; do
   ((10#$d < 50)) && echo "$d"
done | tar czf file1.tgz -T -
```

**Details:**

- `for d in [0-9][0-9]`: Will match entries with 2 digits in current directoery
- `((10#$d < 50))` will compare each (base 10) directory name to `50` and will return success of number is less than `50`
- `tar czf file1.tgz -T -` will read directory names from stdin and create a single gzip tar file `file1.tgz`.

Answer (score 1):

Howdi :)

This is how i would do it, given the info you supplied

Create a list of your directory paths, all 51 of them

```
echo > dirlist.txt ; 
for x in $(seq -w 00 50)
do
echo "/tmp/$x" >> dirlist.txt
done
```

Then use the tar command with the switch -T to load a list from a file:

```
tar -czf myarchive.tar.gz -T dirlist.txt
```

Test your archive , check first 3 lines:

```
tar -tvzf myarchive.tar.gz | head -3
drwxr-xr-x  0 neil   wheel       0 18 Jun 19:36 tmp/00/
drwxr-xr-x  0 neil   wheel       0 18 Jun 19:36 tmp/01/
drwxr-xr-x  0 neil   wheel       0 18 Jun 19:36 tmp/02/
```

Comment: Sound good. Only one issue. For the first 10 files, their names are 00, 01, 02, 03, .... The seq returns 0, 1, 2, 3 instead.

Comment: Yes i saw that as i pasted the results and updated to use seq -w ( padding zeros ) to fix that